# Join more than 2 tables in R using RSQLite

Tags: r, sqlite

I have more than three tables(t1,t2,t3) in my database. I am using RSQLite in R. These databases are formed from data frames.

```
+t1
  fileA valA
     a   12
     b   34
     c   78
     d   98
+t2
fileB valB
     b   45
     e   45
     f  452
     g    6
     d   89
+t3
fileC valC
     a   45
     b   34
     g   45
     i    3
     q    3
```

Lets start with simple scenario (as in reality,I have 16 tables to join which are in GBs), I want to join all the above 3 tables together, in following manner.

---

### Expected Result

```
valA   valB   valC
a   12      NA      45
b   34      45      34
c   78      NA      NA
d   98      89      NA
e   NA      45      NA
f   NA      452     NA
.........
```

I used the following command, but I didnt get the expected result for two tables:

```
    res <-dbSendQuery(con,"SELECT fileA,fileB,valA,valB from t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 On t11.fileA= t2.fileB  UNION select fileA,fileB,valA,valB from t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON t11.fileA= t2.fileB")
```

---

### OUTPUT of above command

```
fileA fileB valA valB
1  <NA>     e <NA>   45
2  <NA>     f <NA>  452
3  <NA>     g <NA>    6
4     a  <NA>   12   NA
5     b     b   34   45
6     c  <NA>   78   NA
7     d     d   98   89
```

So, I can work with above command, if I could join the first two columns of the output.(removing all NAs and keeping the name only, as I have mentioned in the expected result)

Other wise, it would be helpful if anyone could tell me how to join more than three tables.
RSQLite doesnt support RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge these columns with the SQLite [coalesce() core function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce):

```
      select coalesce(fileA,fileB),valA,valB
               from t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 On t1.fileA= t2.fileB
UNION select coalesce(fileA,fileB),valA,valB
               from t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON t1.fileA= t2.fileB
```

Comment: Great..Thanks it worked..Now I can certainly work with. But as I mentioned, I have 16 files which are pretty big ~10000K number of rows. Do you think, is there any way to join all of them together in a same way?

Comment: Try creating a temporary table with a single column, containing all the non-NULL values of all key columns (`CREATE TABLE all_files AS SELECT fileA FROM t1 UNION SELECT fileB from t2 UNION ...`). Then you can join that table to all the other tables with a single LEFT JOIN for each table.